# How can I secure my ASP.NET AJAX application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, security

Ajax seems to give a better user experience, but I'm not so sure if I take the right steps to protect and secure my application.

Is there a checklist of things I must pay attention to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX applications has the same vulnerabilities than other kind of web application:

- XSS
- SQL Injection
- Privilege Escalation
- Information Disclosure
- etc.

But if you want to avoid these common "safe" feel that an AJAX application can give you because normal users will no see the undergoing request you should check the [OWASP AJAX Security Guidelines](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines).

Comment: We've made some progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX does not add security your application. If what you mean is to protect it from hackers there's a lot of things you might consider.

Authentication
Encryption
Validation
Etc..